# passing a 2D structure to a function in c

Tags: c, 2d, structure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing multidimensional array to a function C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742725/passing-multidimensional-array-to-a-function-c)

I want to pass a 2D structure to a function Here is the prototype and the definition of the function and the "typedef" of the function.

```
typedef struct {
BOOLEAN valid;
event_t event_list [MAXEVS];
int num_events;
} calentry_t;

calentry_t calendar[12] [31]; // The declaration of the structure
```

How can i create the definition of the function that i will pass to it the 2d structure and how can i pass it 
please can someone spot my errors

```
InitializeCalendar (calentry_t *calendar){
   int x, y;
for(x = 0; x < 12; x ++) {
    if (x==2){
            for(y = 0; y <= 28; y ++){ 
                (*calendar).calendar[x][y].valid = TRUE;
            }
            for (y=29; y<= 31; y++){
                (*calendar[x][y]).valid = FALSE;
        }
    }
    else if  (x==4 || x==6 || x==9 || x==11){
        for(y = 0; y <= 30; y ++){ 
            (*calendar[x][y]).valid = TRUE;
            }
            for (y=30; y<= 31; y++){
                (*calendar)[x][y].valid = FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void foo(calentry_t mycal[12] [31]) {
  mycal[0][1].valid =1;
}

int main(void) {
  foo(calendar);
  printf("valid: %d\n", calendar[0][1].valid);
}
```

Comment: I want to pass the structure by reference so here is what i did! but it didn't work!
    InitializeCalendar (calentry_t *calendar){
int x, y;
 for(x = 0; x < 12; x ++) {
  if (x==2){
      for(y = 0; y <= 28; y ++){ 
     (*calendar).calendar[x][y].valid = TRUE;
      }
      for (y=29; y<= 31; y++){
       (*calendar[x][y]).valid = FALSE;
   }
  }
  else if  (x==4 || x==6 || x==9 || x==11){
   for(y = 0; y <= 30; y ++){ 
     (*calendar[x][y]).valid = TRUE;
      }
      for (y=30; y<= 31; y++){
       (*calendar)[x][y].valid = FALSE;
   }
  }
 }
}

Comment: and how can i access the elements of the structure through the frunction ?

Comment: This is by reference and I added some example manipulation.

Comment: @user1680944: There is no such thing as pass by reference in C.  The function here actually receives a pointer to array of 12 `calentry_t`.  Everything in C is pass by copy, but you can pass pointers to achieve the same affect.  There is no array copy going on here, you cannot truly pass arrays to functions.

Comment: @user1680944: And on a side note, structure names ending in `_t` are reserved by POSIX for use by the implementation, so... don't do that.

Comment: @EdS."structure names ending in _t are reserved by POSIX" do you have a link for that? `_t` is used by C99 and I could not find anything declaring it reserved in the spec. I am not sure how POSIX plays into this.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html

Comment: It's even more obvious that you shouldn't do it when you consider all of the standard types which use `_t` (`size_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, etc).  Even if it's not specified by the language spec, it seems like a bad idea, no?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I actually prefer `_t` for typedefs and `_s` for structs. Typically you are not redefining basic types so I would not think there is much worry about collision.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the 2D structure inside another structure.

```
typedef struct {
BOOLEAN valid;
event_t event_list [MAXEVS];
int num_events;
} calentry_t;

typedef struct {
    calentry_t calEntries[12][31];
} calendar_t;


calendar_t calendar;

InitializeCalendar(&calendar);


void InitializeCalendar(calendar_t *calendar)
{
    // for example
    calendar->calEntries[0][0].valid = TRUE;
}
```