# Problem in getting the first address of a 3 dimensional pointer into a single dimensional pointer?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

can a single dimension array made to point to the first address of a three dimensional array,
e.g.
   `int *array;
    int ***array3D;
    array=*array3D;`
I need the first array to point to the first address of the second array.
I need only the first address into the pointer. Can anyone please suggest any alternatives to point to the starting address? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to format the code and re post it. Also you can not dereference `void*`. Give example of any other data type.

Comment: @iammilind: But you can dereference `void **` or `void ***`.

Comment: Do you want to point at the *address* of the first element (i.e. point at the pointer), or point at the first element *itself*?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62512/three-dimensional-arrays-of-integers-in-c related question might provide you with some insights

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing happens all the time when you're processing 2D and 3D images.

That you wrote (`array = *array3D`) obviously won't compile though because the types don't match.  `array3D` is an `**int` and array is an `*int`.

If you have `array3D` set up correctly, as such (for example):

```
int ***array3D = new int **[zsize];
for(int z = 0 ; z < zsize ; ++z)     
{
    array3D[z] = new int *[ysize];
    for(int y = 0 ; y < ysize ; ++y)
    {  
         array3D[z][y] = new int [xsize];
    }
}
```

Then you can access things like `array3D[z][y]` (points to the `x=0` element for the given `z` and `y`) 
or `&(array3D[z][y][x])` (points to element `x`, `y`, `z`) 
or `*(array3D[z])` (points to the `y=0` and `x=0` element for the given `z`), and will then all be of type `int *`.  I suggest writing out how your data is organized.

Of course you have to manually delete this structure as well and if you're doing this in a product, you should be careful that you handle exceptions well and don't leak, but this another topic.